# How to measure method efficiency in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

For example, in Prolog [`time/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=time/1) can be used in order to measure the amount of inferences a method call produces.

Is there something similar in Lisp to measure the efficiency of a method to another? That would be extremely useful.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: [Performance and Evaluation of Lisp Systems](http://rpgpoet.com/Files/Timrep.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common Lisp (the standard) offers [`time`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_time.htm), which

> prints various timing data and other information to trace output

Implementations usually provide more profiling tools which will tell you more detailed information about the function calls &c.

There is also a portable profiler called [Metering](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/dkochmanski/metering).